# Does onDestroy of an Activity release a Media Player's resources?

Tags: android, release, onpause, ondestroy

Do I have to call release() of a media player myself or will it be handled when the activity is destroyed/stopped?

Comment: call `mp.release()` on your media player object.

Comment: You should do it in onStop().  onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call release() on the media player in your onDestroy(), I have never dealt with media players, but I know onDestroy() won't handle removing bitmaps from memory, so I would assume media assets are handled in a similar way, only removing them when you tell it to